# How to disable the popup menu of TMemo?

Tags: delphi, menu, firemonkey, memo, tmemo

I'm using Firemonkey TMemo component in my desktop application, I hope that when the user right-clicks or Long-Taps on the Memo , the default menu will not been pop up.

Comment: May I ask why you want to prevent your users from showing a default Popup Menu?

Comment: @SilverWarior My program runs on touch screen(Kiosk App). I use a TMemo to display a long article, only allowing users to scroll up and down to browse the contents of the article. So I don't want a popup menu to pop up when the user long-tap on memo component.

Comment: So why don't you then just disable the `LongTap` interactive gesture of your memo under `Touch->InteractiveGestures->LongTap` property. Granted this won't prevent opening popup menu by right click but as you said in your comment this is run on a touch based kiosk machine which I presume doesn't have mouse attached. Meaning that it would be enough.

Comment: @SilverWarior, This seems like a good idea. But I tried. After setting LongTap to False, the menu can still pop up when long-pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually easy.

Just drop a new `TPopupMenu` on your form and give it a good name (`pmRecipe`, say). Make sure *not* to add any menu items to it! Then simply assign it to your memo's `PopupMenu` property.

However, as a user of your application, I expect a context menu, so I might get annoyed by the lack of such a menu. (I'd also be annoyed by the fact that the app is FMX and not VCL and that the control isn't the native Windows EDIT control, but maybe that's just me.)

Comment: The amount of hybrid apps in the market will make it hard to find the native edit control in an app. Users already lost that distinction.

Comment: Well, personally I have spent most of my time in front of Microsoft Windows computers every day since the age of 7 (25 years ago), and I have never used a Mac or owned a smartphone, so for me the difference is huge.

Comment: You are an intelligent individual. You can see the difference. I have many clients that won't even notice shades of colors I changed. let alone the time I changed the whole underlying platform and they thought it was a simple update (it still cracks me up every time).